# Rails 3, how to make sure Group has_one user.role = groupleader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

My current Group model:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :memberships, :dependent => :destroy
   has_many :users, :through => :memberships
end
```

My Current User Model

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
      has_many :memberships, :dependent => :destroy
      has_many :groups, :through => :memberships
      #some more stuff
    end
```

Membership Model

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id, :group_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group 
end
```

Role Model

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

I have a Ability class and CanCan installed to handle roles.  I have a role type groupleader and need to make sure a Group has only one groupleader...

I think its something like: Group has_one User.role :groupleader... but I know thats not it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to me to have the role on the users table if you want it to determine what the user can do within the context of a group.

Where it *would* make sense is to have it on the `memberships` table for groups and users. Records in this table would then have three columns: `user_id`, `group_id` and `role`.

Then to retrieve the leader for the group you would execute a query like this:

```
group.users.where("memberships.role = 'leader'").first
```

Where `group` is a `Group` object, i.e. `Group.first` or `Group.find(13)`.

This then leaves open the possibility that you can have more than one leader for a group further down the track if required.

---

If your roles are in a separate table, then you can do this:

```
group.users.where("memberships.role_id = ?", Role.find_by_name("leader").id).first
```

Comment: Ok I think I see what your saying.  BUT I think what do I put in the Membership model?  I like the option for more group leaders later.  The model logic is my struggle right now.

Comment: You don't put anything inside the model. You leave the models as they are. You just put the `role` field in the `memberships` table and query off that.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. So my membership table already has user_id and group_id, then you are saying I should add a role_id or just role to the membership table.  Then in my form that sets the join up, I would need to pass in the role.name which would then give the user a role in that group.  

How would i then handle a user who is an group member in one group and a group leader in a different group?